# Count appearances of a value in any column of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, left-join

How can I count up the total appearances of a value in multiple columns?

Raw Table:

```
col1   col2
----   ----
don    sam
jon    sam
mike   lisa
sam    lisa
lisa   beth
```

Result:

```
name   appearances
----   -----------
don    1
sam    3
jon    1
mike   1
lisa   3
beth   1
```

I've tried writing a join where getting the total count is a subquery, but this seems awkward. I'm assuming MySQL has some way to handle this nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `UNION ALL`:

```
select name, count(1) cnt
from (
  select col1 as name from yourtable
  union all
  select col2 from yourtable
  ) t
group by name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/459cf/2)

Results:

```
NAME   CNT 
-----------
beth   1
don    1
jon    1
lisa   3
mike   1
sam    3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select name , count(*) as appearances from
 (
     select col1 as name  from Raw
     union all
     select col2 as name   from Raw 
 )t
 group by name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3979/13)